# Drop response body when redirecting in flask

Tags: python, flask, http-redirect

I got the following going

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return redirect('/world', code=307)
```

However, the response *body* contains some nifty html. As I'm redirecting to an *image* this is normally not so helpful. Instead I would just like to drop the response body, or even better set it to a helpful string or something like that.

Comment: try something like: `from flask import Request; [...]; request.data=""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the HTML redirect response is hard coded in the source code:

[`werkzeug.utils.redirect`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/utils.py#L344)

following their pattern, you can customize a redirect function for your use case like so:

```
from flask import current_app, url_for

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    response = current_app.response_class(
        response="Hello, world",
        status=307,
        mimetype="text/plain"
    )
    response.headers["Location"] = url_for('.world')
    return response
```